# How to insert a string with named parameters in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So I insert a custom string in django template and it has customer parameters.
So the string is a variable that looks like:

```
original_string = "I am test %(value1)s and %(value2)s"
```

now I want to insert this in django with value1 and value2 provided. Can I do this using template and filters or do I have to do this in python backend?

I want something like this:

```
<div>{{original_string | value1='10' value2='20'}}</div>
```

Comment: Can't you use simple context data, like: `<div>I am test {{value1}} and {{value2}}</div>`

Comment: No because this string is not constant

Comment: So I tink a filter is ok, but you can't pass more than one arg to a filter, so you will have to parse it, like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7e270664185576cdf8d3

Comment: Thanks, that sound somewhat reasonable :)

Answer (score 0):

You either need to create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/) or [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) if you need something re-usable, or do it in the view and then output the values.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest handling it in the view.

The way it looks now is going to make the template really difficult to understand without looking at the view, anyway.